# Audio not playing in the wpf application installed via Installshield LE using VS2012

Tags: wpf, mediaelement, installshield-le

I am playing an audio using the `MediaElement`. The `MediaElement` is created as followed in `XAML`:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="audio" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Source="Resources/music.mp3"/ >
```

The audio is played in the constructor as follows:

```
audio.play();
```

This application works perfectly by running via debugging `F5`. However when I created a setup and installed on the machine, the application is running, but the music is not played. Please help!

Comment: did you end up finding an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Know thy dependencies.  Authoring installers is all about automating the deployment of these dependencies.  I can't answer more specifically since I don't have experience with the MediaElement class.  I would think having the framework installed would be enough but perhaps you are missing a codec or something.  Identify that then we can discuss how to install it.